# How can we get other apps' screen time in react native? Is there any library or package available in react native?

Tags: android, react-native, usagestatsmanager, react-native-device-info

I want to get the other app's screen time using my react native app. I'll be using all these data with the permission of user. Is there any npm package or 3rd party library available??

I tried to google it but didn't find any proper solution. Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

> A beginner in the world of Android.